# Center align five columns in a single row without offset - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have five col-md-2 div inside a row div.

To center align i have used col-md-offset-1 with the first col-md-2 div.

I made the column divs Sortable(jqueryui)

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

So now when i move the first col-md-2 div, the offset moves with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/1uuuru2m/4/

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
          $(function() {
          $("#sortable").sortable();
          $("#sortable").disableSelection();
       });
 </script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row content-boxes" id="sortable">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 ui-state-default">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">A</h3>
            </div>
         <div class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item">first child of a</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">second child of a</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">third child of a</li>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ui-state-default">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">B</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item">first child of b</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">second child of b</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">third child of b</li>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ui-state-default">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">C</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item">first child of c</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">second child of c</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">third child of c</li>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ui-state-default">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">D</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item">first child of d</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">second child of d</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">third child of d</li>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ui-state-default">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">E</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item">first child of e</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">second child of e</li>
             <li class="list-group-item">third child of e</li>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I maintain the center-alignment inside the row div without using offset on first col div?

Comment: Use an empty col-md-1? http://jsfiddle.net/zrjtr4yt/

Comment: exactly what i wanted, thanks! will mark as accepted answer

Comment: No worries, added my answer so other people can see that this question has been answered.

Comment: BTW to mark my answer as correct click the dotted outline of the the check mark next to the up / down arrows on my answer. (Just saying as I see you are new and people often miss it)

Comment: No problem, I know how stack overflow works(have accepted two answers in the past).I am just new to how everything else works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an empty col-md-1 instead of offset so that it doesn't move around. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrjtr4yt/).

```
<div class="row content-boxes" id="sortable">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 ui-state-default">
```

goes to

```
<div class="row content-boxes" id="sortable">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ui-state-default">
```